# What is the measure of the length of the tetrahedron?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Four balls of radius 1 are mutually tangent, three resting on the floor and the fourth resting on the others. A tetrahedron, each of whose edges have length s, is circumscribed around the balls. Then what is the measure of s?

I got s = 2root(3) + 2 but the answer said it was s = 2root(6) + 2 and I tried to figure out where I went wrong but I couldn't see the problem. This was the 1980 AHSME problem 26.

Comment: Can you show how you calculated that value?

Comment: What you are probably finding is the length of the sides around $3$ balls on the ground but that will get you the planes standing vertical which will make a prism and not a tetrahedron, with not even touching the 4th ball on top of the three. To make tetrahedron, they need to be slanted which would increase the side lengths.

Comment: Yes that was what I did. How can I take into account the slant?

Comment: Compute the height of the center of an equilateral tetrahedron of edge $2$ above its base (this is the tetrahedron with the centers of the spheres as vertices). The height of the center of the equilateral tetrahedron around the spheres will be $1$ higher. What  is the linear ratio between these two tetrahedra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The centers of the spheres are $2$ units apart, so consider the equilateral tetrahedron with edge $2$.

In an equilateral triangle of side $2$, each vertex is $\frac2{\sqrt3}$ from the center of the triangle. Thus, the the fourth vertex of the tetrahedron must be at a height $\sqrt{4-\frac43}=\frac23\sqrt6$ above its base. Thus, the center of the tetrahedron is $\frac16\sqrt6$ above its base.

The center of the tetrahedron around the spheres is therefore $1+\frac16\sqrt6$ above the plane on which it sits.

The linear ratio between the tetrahedron with the centers as vertices to the tetrahedron around the spheres is $\frac{1+\frac16\sqrt6}{\frac16\sqrt6}=1+\sqrt6$ and so the edge of the tetrahedron around the spheres must be $2\!\left(1+\sqrt6\right)=2+2\sqrt6$.